# What kind of spider is this? From New Zealand

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

Found this spider in my bin, sorry for poor quality photo, has a massive red bum, haven't seen one like it, can anyone identify it?, around the size of my finger or thumbnail. I am from New Zealand

[image: Spider]

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please [edit] your post to include as much of the following essential information to improve your chances of getting a good answer: 1) one or more clear closeup photos of the organism (photos from multiple angles if possible)); 2) the location (e.g. country and region — the more specific the better) where you observed this organism; 3) habitat information; and 4) an estimate of the size of the organism (human nails vary significantly). ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the [help] pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be the [False Widow Spider](https://www.citscihub.nz/Phil_Bendle_Collection:False_widow_spider_(Steatoda_grossa)) (*Steatoda grossa*), which is a cosmopolitan species found over much of the world.

> The female S. grossa is 6-10.5 mm in length and dark coloured with a round, bulbous abdomen. Typical colouration ranges from reddish brown to black, with light-coloured markings.